# VBA 正規表現でHTMLのリンクタグ(aタグ)の属性を、別タグにして『rel=”noopener noreferrer”』を付加するように変換したい。

Tags: html, 正規表現, vba

ExcelVBAで、HTMLを自動出力するソフトを作っています。

リンクタグを全て別タグ(別ウインドウ)で開かせるように
変換したいと思っています。また、セキュリティ対策に自動で
rel=”noopener noreferrer”が追加されるようにしたいのですが、
正規表現が不慣れなものでどのようにパターンを書けばいいのかが
解りません。

HTML内のすべてのaタグでかまわないので、別タグで開くように書き換える
コードを、パターン付きでお教えいただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

正規表現は`"<a +"`で置換文字列は`"<a target=""_blank"" rel=""noopener noreferrer"""`にすることで`<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href=...`の形にできます。
下記は少し発展させてhrefの後にtarget="_blank"などを追加する例です。
なお元の文字列にtargetやrel属性が入っていた場合の判定処理は考慮していません。
必要に応じて条件分岐などを追加してください。

**サンプルコード**

```
Sub ボタン1_Click()
    Dim reg As Object
    Set reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With reg
        .Pattern = "(<a.+?)(href\s*=\s*"".+?"")" 
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With

    Dim srcStr As String
    Dim newStr As String
    srcStr = "<a href=""http://hoge/"">a href=""ここは変換しない""</a>" + vbCrLf + _
    "<a href = ""http://fuga:1234?piyo""></a>" + vbCrLf + _
    "<a href=""http://foo"" target=""_blank"">この場合はtargetが重複する</a>" 
    newStr = reg.Replace(srcStr, "$1$2 target=""_blank"" rel=""noopener noreferrer""")
    MsgBox newStr
End Sub
```

**実行結果**

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Excel
---------------------------
<a href="http://hoge/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">a href="ここは変換しない"</a>

<a href = "http://fuga:1234?piyo" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"></a>

<a href="http://foo" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">この場合はtargetが重複する</a>
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ですが、実は＞なお元の文字列にtargetやrel属性が入っていた場合の判定処理は考慮していません。
の部分が重要なため、そこも踏まえた回答を頂ければ幸いです。